# How can I create a new Phoenix project using the latest 1.6.0-dev version?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to try out the new phx.gen.auth and esbuild systems. I know 1.6.0-dev is not released yet but on Twitter people are talking about how good it is.

I can't seem to find a way to create a new app using this unreleased version.

Comment: The Phoenix repository's [Readme](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix#generating-a-phoenix-project-from-unreleased-versions) may be useful.

Answer (score 5):

You can tell `mix` to install the Phoenix 1.6 release candidate like so:

```sh
$ mix archive.install hex phx_new 1.6.0-rc.0
```

If you don't supply the release candidate (`rc.0`) then mix will tell you the closest match which may be a good idea as new release candidates could be released.

```
$ mix archive.install hex phx_new 1.6.0

** (Mix) No matching version for phx_new 1.6.0 (from: mix.exs) in registry

While there is no package matching the requirement above, there are pre-releases available:

  * 1.6.0-rc.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did this today, here are the steps I took.

clone phoenix 1.6 down locally somewhere and install the deps:

```
git@github.com:phoenixframework/phoenix.git
cd phoenix
mix deps.get
```

Then you want to read the installer README here https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/tree/master/installer which tells you to uninstall your current phoenix installer:

```
mix archive.uninstall phx_new
```

and then build and install a new one from the current source:

```
cd installer
MIX_ENV=prod mix do archive.build, archive.install
```

Now you can use `mix phx.new` in another folder to generate a new phoenix app using the latest master that you just cloned.

**NOTE**: the generated phoenix project is going to have a line in `mix.exs` pointing to the latest phoenix on github:

```
defp deps do
  [
    {:phoenix, github: "phoenixframework/phoenix", override: true},
    ...
  ]
end
```

This will obviously change as new commits are added, but you can point to you local by changing it to a path based dep if you want:

```
defp deps do
  [
    {:phoenix, path: "../phoenix", override: true},
    ...
  ]
end
```

The reason you might want to do this (like I did) is because you want to include some un-merged PRs or try tweaking some things locally yourself. For example, running `mix phx.gen.auth` is going to use the mix task from the defined phoenix dependency in your mix file, NOT the mix task that was present at the time of you building the installer.